# Function getting called on the load of page

Tags: javascript

```
for (var key in obj[i]) {
    dataDump[key] = textField.value;
    var callback = function(zeKey){
       return function(e){
          dataDump[zeKey] = e.source.value;
       }; 
    }(key);
    textField.addEventListener('change', callback);
}
```

When I load the window, this function gets called automatically, which I don't want and instead I want this to be called only when I do a change.

The main point is calling `function(zeKey){...}(key)`. When you do so, key, which is a string is copied as a parameter (zeKey) to your anonymous function.

Comment: Which function? The function that sets the callback? By the looks of it, isn't it supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

The following

```
var callback = function(zeKey){
    return function(e){
        dataDump[zeKey] = e.source.value;
    }; 
}(key);
```

1. Calls the anonymous function with argument `zeKey`.
2. This anonymous function returns another function. This returned function is assigned to the callback.

If **1** what you mean by "the function is getting called" then this is expected behavior.

This entire code should be called only after DOM is ready. Place all these in a function and make sure the function is called only on [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) or (jQuery's) [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

The function returned by the function will be called only during the callback.

Comment: Can i write two listners for an a field.. i mean.. textField.addEventListener('change', callback, callback2) where callback2 will be called only during change... a normal function

Comment: @John Cooper You can write multiple listeners for the same event for an element (that is why _add_`EventListener`). You do so by, well, adding two listeners: `element.addEventListener('click', function1);` `element.addEventListener('click', function2);`

Answer (score 0):

Add these code once dom is created. If above code is inside a function, attach to window.load or write these code at the end of page.